# Why does (~10) equal -11 in C++ (bitwise operators)

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I am learning C++ and was wondering why this was.

I know that the first bit handles whether the value is negative.

However, if you have 0 1 0 1 0 and do ~, you will get 1 0 1 0 1 right?

Someone please help me out with this. Thanks!

Comment: Please add the code that causes this confusion.

Comment: Highly related (if not a dupe): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655257/twos-complement-binary-form?rq=1

Comment: So what value do you think 1 0 1 0 1 should be? I expect you are thinking it should be -5, that would be true if your computer used *signed magnitude* but almost every computer uses a different system called *two's complement*. Google that and it will explain everything.

Comment: There's no code, its just the concept.

Comment: Here's something to blow your mind. ~0 is not -0, there's no such thing. ~0 gives you -1. Ponder on that, for a few minutes, and maybe things will become more clear to you.

Comment: Unless you're running on a computer with 5-bit words, you'll never have either 01010 or 10101.  The closest you can get on most computers in as 8-bit char, which would be 00001010, so the bitwise negation of that would be 11110101.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, if you have 0 1 0 1 0 and do ~, you will get 1 0 1 0 1 right?

That is true if you look at only those 5 bits. If `int` is represented by 32 bits, there are 27 more bits that you have not considered. There are 27 zero bits to the left to represent the number 10. Hence, `~10` will have 27 bits to the left that are 1.

What you get is:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1
```

In a two's complement representation, that number is -11.

Answer (score 1):

Most processors use a method called Two's Complement to store negative numbers.

This method, though seem kind of an overhead to clip from Positive 2 Negative, has a very good impact on Adding/Subtracting numbers.

You can review how Two's complement works in many examples ([here is one](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~tomf/notes/cps104/twoscomp.html))

I don't like messing with the bits, so i use a different method,
and to give you an intuition about Two's Complement, i'll elaborate.

Two's complement divide the range into two parts:
So on your 5-bit example [0, (2^5-1)=31]:

signed will split it into two parts:
  - first from 0 to 15...
  - second from -16 to -1...

therefore your example:

- 10101 = 21...
- 21 falls in second part so we subtract the size of the half from it (16) >> 21-16=5
- now, add that to the Second part peek value (-16) >> -16 + 5 = -11

Hope I was clear enough...